# How to get out of nested loop in python

Tags: python

I have been cracking my head the whole time. I am aware that this is a very simple task of loops, however, I am unable to get the second loop to be added into the code. please help me take a look.

So, in short this program is suppose to:

```
# Given a list of numbers and a number k,
# return whether any two numbers from the list add up to k.
# For example, given [10, 15, 3, 7] and k of 17,
# "return true since 10 + 7 is 17.
```

and I need some guide on the looping of the list.
it is my day 2 on python. Thanks a lot for the help in advance!

So, I got the input ready, function to get 2 inputs from the list add them up and compare with `K`. 
The issue is getting the numbers within the list to add with themselves.

```
import os
import subprocess
# Given a list of numbers and a number k,
# return whether any two numbers from the list add up to k.
# For example, given [10, 15, 3, 7] and k of 17,
# "return true since 10 + 7 is 17.
# Bonus: Can you do this in one pass

# get input for list untill enter
list = list()

num = int(input("how many number you want: "))
print("enter the number in array")
for i in range(int(num)):
    n = int(input("num :"))
    list.append(int(n))
print('Total number in Array: ', num)

# get input for k
try:
    k = int(input("enter value of K: "))
except ValueError:
    print("This is not a whole number.")

# show list and k
print('Value in Array: ', list, 'Value of k: ', k)


# check if any 2 add up to k
def addncompar(list1, list2, kinput):
    print("---------------------start of function")
    print("K is: ", kinput)
    total = list1 + list2
    print("a1 is :", list1)
    print("b1 is :", list2)
    print("sum is :", total)
    print("---------------------end of function")
    if total != kinput:
        return False
    else:
        return True

    # for each 1 item in the list compare to each item in the list.if condition 
    true= break,else compare another number.


    i = 0
    while i < int(num):
        print("while i staring is ", i)
        if i == num:
            break
        else:
            for y in range(num):
                print("y staring is ", y)
                print("num staring is ", num)
                if y + 1 == num:
                    y = 0
                print("i staring in y loop is ", i)

                if addncompar(list[i], list[y + 1], k) == True:
                    a1 = list[i]
                    b1 = list[y + 1]
                    break
                else:
                    print("y has been added at else")
                    print("y ending is:", y)
                    if list[y + 1] == num:
                        print("i has been added")
                        i += 1
                        print("i has become :", i)
                        print("y after i added:", y)

                    else:
                        print("y has been added")
                        y += 1

        # if true
        # display
        print("value 1 + value 2 = k")
        print(a1, "+", b1, "=", k)
        break


        # else
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation; that's especially important for nested loops. You can copy/paste your whole code block in one go, highlight it all, and use ctrl + k, or the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: for most programming languages, one rather clean way to break out of a nested loop is to put the nested loop into a function/procedure/method/whatever and return from that

Comment: Yes I am aware that indentation is important infact it kept on prompting me when it comes to python. Thank you everyone for you help. I will take alook again with your example. I will take alook at putting loop into function. Trying to do a program per day. Thanks guys for a your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use a boolean flag:

```
ret = False
i = 0
while i < int(num):
    ...
        for y in range(num):
            ...
            if addncompar(list[i], list[y + 1], k) == True:
                a1 = list[i]
                b1 = list[y + 1]
                ret = True
                break
            ...
        if ret:
            break
    ...
```

Or use the fancy `else` of a `for` loop:

```
i = 0
while i < int(num):
    ...
        for y in range(num):
            ...
            if addncompar(list[i], list[y + 1], k) == True:
                a1 = list[i]
                b1 = list[y + 1]
                break
            ...
        else:
            continue
        break
    ...
```

The `else` part is executed  if the `for` was not "broken" (i. e, exited using `break`statement).

Comment: Thanks for the 2 different bits of advice, I shall take a look, all I was taught in school was break is something that everyone should avoid using.

Comment: Crazy teaching. What on earth else is one supposed to do, when searching for the first entity in a list satisfying some condition?  Test all the others anyway?

Comment: Upvoted for the second example, using loop else clause to continue an outer loop. I'd never have thought of it. Beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just keep it clean and nice:

```
import itertools

def isAdded(numList, k):
    for num in range(0, len(numList)):
            for subNums in itertools.combinations(numList, num):
                b = sum(int(i) for i in subNums)              
                if b == k:        
                   print("The numbers that add up ", k, " are: ", subNums)

k = 17
numList = [10, 15, 3, 7]
isAdded(numList, k)
```

OUTPUT:

> The numbers that add up  17  are:  (10, 7)

[pyfiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/09c195b9-eadf-4250-afaa-983d6884f560/?i=true)

Comment: `for num in range(1, len(numList)+1):` ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Ah, my bad. typo. fixed.

Comment: Wow thanks alot. Omg.. so many step all in these few lines.. regarding the import itertools. Is it like a recommend solution? Or is it best to avoid? Is it something like import re?

Comment: @Chris like I said, cleaner, nicer and shorter. *combinations(numList, num) returns num length subsequences of elements from the input iterable*. You can read more here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D you're welcome to edit and identify any fixes, cheers.

Comment: This is **SUPER EXTREMELY INEFFICIENT !!!** Finding all combinations... BLOWING MIND!

Comment: By the way, this should not be an answer. The OP asked for a way to exit out of both loops, not a completely different solution.

Comment: @JosuéCortina finding all the combinations is a way you would know which combination makes it to the sum, giving a shorter or another way to achieve the output doesn't count as "not-an-answer". Cheers

Comment: The question is as long as there is a combination just return True will do. with this method i found out that as the number gets larger there are more combination even more than just 2 number added together. and if its too small. it could oso end up with a single ans eg: sum(3,0) k = 3. i am looking into if there is a way to set restriction using this combination tool. 
Still its alot faster than and cheers for the suggestion.